# How to send push notification from Kamailio? Both GCM and APNS

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, sip, kamailio

I am creating custom SIP client (Android & IOS), which uses **Kamailio** as a proxy and it's required to send push notification from **Kamailio** to the clients when a call towards that client reached on **Kamailio**.
I found a module for **APNS** here https://github.com/tvntsr/push. But I am developing both Android and IOS clients.
So What mechanism can I use on the Android side?
Is there any module available for GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) in Kamailio?
Or is there any other mechanism for availing both **GCM & APNS** on Kamailio?

Answer (score 0):

Reasonable version is write custom module or do insert into mongodb or mysql )with event message), after that process it by external script.

Also possible do curl(http) request to external module, but that block core in kamailio. Avoid block core, result is zero perfomance.

Unfortanly any method also require delay and re-invite after push done, so this project is doable, but not for average kamailio "expert" (for sure not for novice).